# Visual Studio App Center Private Cocoapod

Tags: ios, build, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

My iOS project includes some private pods. I have gone through the steps on my local machine (as well as team members) to use private pods outlined [here](https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/create-and-distribute-private-libraries-with-cocoapods-5b6507b57a03).

How do I add the same process for VS App Center to update and retrieve the repo?

Currently, I get this in the build output:

`[command]/usr/local/bin/pod install --repo-update
Updating local specs repositories
Cloning spec repo fooBar from git@github.com:fooBar/Podspec.git
[!] Unable to add a source with url git@github.fooBar/Podspec.git named fooBar.
You can try adding it manually in ~/.cocoapods/repos or via pod repo add.
[error]/usr/local/bin/pod failed with return code: 1
[error]The 'pod' command failed with error: /usr/local/bin/pod failed with return code: 1`

Comment: I don't know anything about VS App Center but if it is like other CI environments, it starts with a default environment each time. You will need to add your `pod repo add...` command to your CI script

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was trying the same and it looks like it's impossible to achieve what you want in way you want.

**TL;DR:**

Use [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) for your private dependencies and GIT LFS to store compiled dependency frameworks.
I've used GIT LFS to store `Carthage/Build` directory (that's actually all you need to compile your app).
I'm still using Cocoapods in my project to maintain public dependencies (somehow it's required in my project).

**Why this way?**

Because I've found this in AppCenter's docs:

> 2. Is your app fairly simple, without many customizations, and is the build pretty straightforward?
>
> In App Center, if your app follows the usual standard layout on the respective platform and does not rely on a lot of external build steps, App Center finds the app automatically in your repository and builds it right away.

(see: [Choose the right service for app builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/choose-between-services))

So I realised that I really should use the simplest way to build the app on AppCenter. Hope that helps, even thought the answer came after such a long time :)